# How to insert a tab (or a tab's whitespaces) even if suggestions are available in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

Say I need to insert a tab character (or whitespaces that will be inserted by a tab key) in VSCode but there are available suggestions. Is there a way to insert a tab without first canceling the suggestions?

Comment: There is a way to do that but, of course, the suggest widget will close anyway (and a tab inserted)  - I assume that is acceptable?

Comment: And do you have the setting `Editor: Tab Completion` set to `off`?

Comment: have you tried using the command `type` in a key binding, type the unicode character `\u0009`, see key bind doc page

Comment: @rioV8 I tested this yesterday, no need for unicode there, just `\t`.

Answer (score 0):

Try making this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`):

```json
{
  "key": "tab",
  "command": "type",
  "args": {
    "text": "\t"
  },
  "when": "suggestWidgetVisible"
}
```

Now whenever you tab with the suggest widget open, you will get a tab, not the suggestion completion.